# How to Ignore testing file in specs tests folder with Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have a folder [specs](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/tree/master/specs/1.x.x/scripts/array) which contains test suites and I want to ignore `omit.spec.js` from testing temporarily.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--testpathignorepatternsarray)

```
npm test -- --testPathIgnorePatterns=omit
```